# Adding Bool values to every element of matrix array (two dimensional array) in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array that represents every coordinate of a maze:

```
var maze:[[Int]]

let column = [Int](repeating: 0, count: y)
self.maze = ([[Int]](repeating: column, count: x))
```

I need to assign 4 Bool values to every single coordinate:

```
canMoveUp = false
canMoveDown = false
canMoveLeft = false
canMoveRight = false
```

The problem is I already have a lot of code written using `maze:[[Int]]`. Is there a way of creating an extra object reaching `maze[[Int]]` and adding bool values to its every element not affecting the original maze var? If not: just an example of declaring 2D array with Bool values for every element would be really helpful.
I am at the very beginning of my developer career, please be indulgent. Any help is much appreciated!

---

Comment: Every element has its Int value. I want to keep it it as it is and add Bool data to an element as well. Like having a fingerprint of maze car but with a possibility to add another type of data to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way of creating an extra object reaching maze[[Int]] and adding bool values to its every element not affecting the original maze var?

**No.** `Int` is a fundamental type, not something you can extend.

You *could* create a second maze array with the new data in the corresponding locations, but that's a terrible idea; trying to keep two data structures in sync at all times is always an exercise in pain.

What you *should* do is to refactor your code so that you're using an appropriate type for your maze data instead of the single `Int` that you're using now. If you do it right, you'll only need to do it once, and from then on you can add new data to each cell in the maze with much less effort. Create a data structure that contains everything that you currently need, like:

```
struct MazeElement {
    var up = false
    var down = false
    var left = false
    var right = false
    var count = 0
}

let columns = 4
let rows = 3
var maze = [[MazeElement]](repeating: [MazeElement](repeating:MazeElement(), count: rows), count: columns)
```

Next you'll have find all the places in your code where you expect `maze` to be a 2D array of `Int`, and change each one so that it expects a `MazeElement` instead. In practice, that mostly means that lines like:

```
let foo = maze[i][j]
```

need to be changed to:

```
let foo = maze[i][j].count
```

But the benefit is that now it's easy to also get the directional information for each cell:

```
let canMoveUp = maze[i][j].up
let canMoveLeft = maze[i][j].left
```

Better yet, when you decide to add some new data to each element, you won't have to do all that work all over again... just change the definition of `MazeElement` to include the new data:

```
struct MazeElement {
    var up = false
    var down = false
    var left = false
    var right = false
    var count = 0
    var color = UIColor.white
}
```